# Integrate SCORM in LMS

Tags: java, scorm

I have developed a Learning Management System using Java.I have to import and access the SCORM courses in my LMS.I have studied about SCORM  in scorm.com but i have no clear idea of integrating it to my LMS.So can anyone give me the steps to integrate it to my LMS or link that has good explanation.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read the SCORM documents on the ADL website. http://www.adlnet.org/

Answer (score 7):

My name is Brian Caudill, I am the founder of JCA Solutions "The SCORM Authority"

SCORM has 2 versions, SCORM 1.2 and SCORM 2004. There are a few open source projects that can assist in integrating SCORM 1.2 and there are some paid for applications.

Basically what you are looking for is called a "SCORM Adapter".

I have compiled a list of 8 offerings below, hopefully it helps.

### Paid Applications

Name: Simple SCORM LMS Adapter
Company: JCA Solutions (we sell this product)
Implements: SCORM 1.2 / SCORM 2004
App stack: JavaScript
URL: jcasolutions.com/simple-scorm-lms-adapter

Name: SCORM Engine
Company: Rustici Software
App Stack: .Net, JavaScript, web service
Implements: SCORM 1.2 / 2004
URL: scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-engine/

Name: Icodeon SCORM Player
Company: Icodeon Software
App Stack: .Net or Java
Implements: SCORM 1.2 / 2004
URL: icodeon.com/product.html

Name: Xyleme SCORM Player
Company: Xyleme
App Stack: unknown
Implements: upgrades SCORM 1.2 to SCORM 2004
URL: xyleme.com/product/scorm-player

### Open source

Name: VSSCORM
Implements: SCORM 1.2
App Stack: PHP / MYSQL
URL: vsscorm.net/run-time-environment-rte/run-time-environment-downloads/ 

NAME: SCORMPool 
Implements: SCORM 2004 4th Ed
App stack: JavaScript
URL: scormpool.com/search/download.aspx

Name: ADL SCORM Resource Libraries by  jjmarks 
Implements: SCORM 1.2 and possibly 2004
App Stack: C#.NET
URL: sourceforge.net/projects/adllib

Name: Dotnetscorm
Implements: SCORM 1.2
App stack: .NET
URL: dotnetscorm.codeplex.com

Comment: This is fine Brian. I am choosing SCORMPool. I have downloaded it from the link you have given but i have problems in integrating it in my LMS.I have searched for the documentation but i could not find it. So can you give me the instructions for integrating with my LMS(using JAVA) and connecting to my database(to store tracking time and status of the course)

Comment: did u find scrompool documentation now ?

Comment: @JCA Solutions - If I want to integrate the player can I use Simple SCORM LMS Adapter ?? how it is different then SCORM provided by Rustic?